# How to Get All Movies (not videos) with YouTube V3 API

Tags: youtube-api

I want to list all the movies available on YouTube (i.e. those available via //youtube.com/movies).  I can see how to query those using API V2, but this has a limit of 1000 responses.

With the V3 api I can see the category for movies has id 30, but I can't work out how to get all movies with this category.  The only category queries appear to search on guide categories, which are different.

Any clues on how I can get this list?  Please help if you can!

Comment: Why on earth would you want to list all movies on YouTube? They give you APIs for doing pretty much anything legitimate that you'd want to do with all that data. And if they don't, well then they probably don't want you doing that.

Comment: See http://movies.tanktop.tv.  We're trying to list all on-demand movies available in the UK across all the popular services.  There are only 36k movies on youtube - and probably fewer available in the UK.

Comment: I stand corrected. `"movie" != "video"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my current answer - still working on it so I've not accepted it yet

I worked out the categoryId for Movies is 30.  I then did a search for videos using this categoryId, and the query string "movie" (just because I need to put something). This gives more than 1000 results, and google limits queries to 1000 results even with the v3 api.

So I need to partition my query.  I have been able to do this with publishedBefore and publishedAfter.  Note these are upload dates and not release dates.

This gives me a list of movies.

Here's a sample query
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?nextPageToken=CDIQAA&publishedBefore=2010-02-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&maxResults=50&q=movie&videoCategoryId=30&part=id%2Csnippet&key=yourAPIKeyHere&type=video&publishedAfter=2010-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z

Once I have the movie IDs I query the individual movie ids

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=50&id=O7cSKNevYQc%2CN84-SoboM6c%2C9K_WO3lqDSc%2CWTJP0Z-bknc%2CdF9hwjeRbGE%2CPnefvJ9T1N0%2CDuM6B4yKgTU%2C0tI8iP2f58I%2Cr4lNJEnY0FA%2COFnMrx6yEcA%2CmUZUAeqOmbg%2CDjq0tHK-KTo%2CkY44nxk0qjg%2CcLYkUR5MY14%2CTZpcfYOOEXA%2C-0jA9DMX8Qs%2C2TQDV1m4X2s%2CBh3Tye1OQvk%2Ct5IwjMDVNz4%2CkOi88X6xeKg%2Ck53CuaAUtik%2CNaRuenqLb9g%2Cn9h-0Wgix7Q%2CQG8SiW2a_l0%2Cmk-D66Z1Ydg%2ClvmwofckpNc%2CgRQK4fTXfBM%2CPZHgLy48R3Q%2CwczeO0DVM0g%2CTpMDTG3dEYE%2C6JI8pN7BqEQ%2COv9yllk3hsY%2CsN09sfLPu0g%2CbfhLYJGN948%2CPiWusdK75Ys%2CeE5jh0YwTCY%2C_cIw3vr2Q18%2CSA4xg_k0aqI%2CUZdha0zTM6w%2CwUdkDSIBw94%2CAhR-LDSIOaI%2C1XMt40vJayU%2C83fPx5-aUL8%2CmJLjaKzu7PQ%2CZvj_zRGnwU0%2CtyIPMd7JXOA%2CToE10sC36KQ%2COVKXjOW6cD8%2CLPW1cXVjMrg&key=LALALA

I still then need to filter the results by looking at the following json in the results

```
  "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT1H35M14S",
    "regionRestriction": {
     "allowed": [
      "US"
     ]
    }
```

Unfortunately this still doesn't give me the movie year or director (which are useful for working out which movie this actually is), or the price (which, you know, people find interesting)

Answer (score 5):

I believe that you can get the autogenerated channels, related to movies, and use their id to get the playlists related to this channels and finally the items (videos..) from this playlists, that must be the videos related to the movies of the selected channels:

Retrieve movie channels:

Request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=movies&type=channel&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Partial response

```
"items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#channel",
    "channelId": "UCczhp4wznQWonO7Pb8HQ2MQ"
   },
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"eTr3dHIt5_K9qdGtRKL-5XdpiQI/sQpwXP-0MUEZzOQx4F0yKj0eUR4\"",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2005-12-15T03:07:36.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCczhp4wznQWonO7Pb8HQ2MQ",
    "title": "movies",
    "description": "YouTube Movies (United States).",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "http://i.ytimg.com/i/czhp4wznQWonO7Pb8HQ2MQ/1.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "http://i.ytimg.com/i/czhp4wznQWonO7Pb8HQ2MQ/mq1.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "http://i.ytimg.com/i/czhp4wznQWonO7Pb8HQ2MQ/hq1.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  },
```

e.g. Get the list of movies in channel "YouTube Movies (United States)"

Request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=UCczhp4wznQWonO7Pb8HQ2MQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Partial response:

```
{

   "id": "PLjygWhZE6KY0Uhw12FsAc8raAClz0l71C",
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"eTr3dHIt5_K9qdGtRKL-5XdpiQI/TWrkoCkmJvq14neCcutnApHMMgU\"",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2012-12-06T20:11:40.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCczhp4wznQWonO7Pb8HQ2MQ",
    "title": "The Nicolas Cage Collection",
    "description": "From panicked fathers to spirits of vengeance, Nicolas Cage has done it all.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nHiy8SVZdpU/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nHiy8SVZdpU/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nHiy8SVZdpU/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  },
```

Get items from this playlist:

Request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PLjygWhZE6KY0Uhw12FsAc8raAClz0l71C&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Partial response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"eTr3dHIt5_K9qdGtRKL-5XdpiQI/KSlqEnNGq36l47_k9W3fd79KfYQ\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 15,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "items": [
  {

   "id": "PLcBtbpFAOApiV34TU797yEFAUZuwhFrvJya3MqlZWkGM",
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"eTr3dHIt5_K9qdGtRKL-5XdpiQI/C_xTa48Xof7giXobSula2vWX43A\"",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2012-12-06T20:12:49.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCczhp4wznQWonO7Pb8HQ2MQ",
    "title": "Stolen",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nHiy8SVZdpU/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nHiy8SVZdpU/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nHiy8SVZdpU/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "playlistId": "PLjygWhZE6KY0Uhw12FsAc8raAClz0l71C",
    "position": 0,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "nHiy8SVZdpU"
    }
   }
  },
  {

   "id": "PLcBtbpFAOApiV34TU797yED-1zeMCoMGVxtVgtX9ZdsQ",
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"eTr3dHIt5_K9qdGtRKL-5XdpiQI/LgSyqtZkwJXv6-2ajW0g-FsgddQ\"",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2012-12-06T20:19:26.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCczhp4wznQWonO7Pb8HQ2MQ",
    "title": "Trespass",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/J_7Zug6ouy4/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/J_7Zug6ouy4/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/J_7Zug6ouy4/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "playlistId": "PLjygWhZE6KY0Uhw12FsAc8raAClz0l71C",
    "position": 1,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "J_7Zug6ouy4"
    }
   }
  },
```

and in this way you can create the list of videos as you want

Comment: Oh frabjous day!  I didn't think there might be a single channel for GB movies and got hung up on categories.  Looks really promising

Comment: Gah, not sure this does it.  I can get the playlists for the GB movies, but there are only 6 of them and they are specific topics, not everything available.  I don't think they add up to the whole collection